# Can DOMContentLoaded event not be fired in any circumstance?

Tags: javascript

For example chained events of this kind won't work because the event will be fired only once.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    alert('This should show up');
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    alert('This will never show up');
    });
});
```

Particularly my doubt is in the case you put your scripts at the bottom of the HTML, as they will be parsed when the DOM has already been loaded. More, if there are many things in your script before your event because the event could be fired before the parser reaches the `addEventListener` statement.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the javascript:

```
// myscript.js
// ... many things ...
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    alert('Will this always happen?');
});
```

I've tried this and it works, but my question is if there is any case where it wouldn't and if there is any guarantee that it will be fired at least once, also in offline.

Comment: if your event handler is attached in the first `<script>` tag, and called during the script's parsing (not nested in some async func), you can be sure it will fire. scripts are part of the DOM, and the only way to stop the DOM before it reaches the end of the markup is to call `window.stop()`, which won't block the execution of its own ownerNode's content. i.e `<script>window.stop(); window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ...)</script>` will fire, while `<script>window.stop()</script><script>window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ...)</script>` won't.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no case where that wouldn't work, as long as the script containing the handler for `DOMContentLoaded` is in the document, before `</body>`, and not inside other event handlers, like nested `DOMContentLoaded` handlers or `window.onload` handlers, it will always work.

Not sure what you mean by "offline", but as long as the document can be gotten and loaded, the event will fire, regardless of being online or not ?

Comment: Please, can you provide a reference? (What I meant  by offline is that the document is not downloaded, ie. a local file).

Comment: References to JS methods are generally [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded). And yes, `DOMContentLoaded` works the same way with a document loaded from a local resource.

Comment: MDN says _event is fired when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed_. My question is more if the event can fire before I add the listener. For example if it finished parsing the document before the end of the script file is reached where I call `addEventListener`.

Comment: As long as that script file is inside the document, and there aren't really many other places to put it, it will be executed before the document has completely loaded.